# I am facing problem will installing webpack by npm install webpack?

Tags: node.js, json, npm

npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...pes/node":"^12.6.9","'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:

npm ERR!     C:\Users\Dubey\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2020-05-30T08_45_02_091Z-debug.log

Please help me to get over this error.

Comment: Looks like you have a truncated package.json in one of the packages being installed. Try again, and if it keeps failing, do "npm cache clear" and try again (but it will need to download every file in your cache again)

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt I have already tried " npm cache clear " and npm cache clear --force" but then also is face the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
npm cache clean --force
```

Answer (score 0):

"*Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near*" happens when you have a syntactically wrong `package.json`.

Try to copy paste your `package.json` file (*all the file*) [here](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com).

This tool will report any errors with your file if you have any.